# Combining commands.getstatusoutput with an object not working?

Tags: python

you can check the below code obviously its not working since im new to python however the code is self explanatory and appreciate some guidance:
im trying to delete a folder like this:

-- cmd command--

```
rm -R /var/cache/zoneminder/events/DoorBird/2019-09-02
```

--- broken python code ---

```
import commands
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
yesterday = print(today - datetime.timedelta(days = 1))
print commands.getstatusoutput('rm -R /var/cache/zoneminder/events/DoorBird/' + yesterday)
```

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: In `yesterday = print(today - datetime.timedelta(days = 1))`, is `print` necessary?

Comment: no the print is not necessary please disregard it, my python version is : 2.7.15+

Answer (score 0):

here's the correct code if anyone is wondering:

```
import commands
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
print commands.getstatusoutput('rm -R /var/cache/zoneminder/events/DoorBird/' + yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```